# Insert Data From One Table To Another - MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

so I'm trying to make a small online store. I have 2 tables: `cart_products` and `order_products`. Inside these tables, two types of items that can be added into the cart: `promotion` and `products`. These two types of items are stored on different tables called: `promotions` and `products`.

Initially all products/promotions are added to the `cart` table, once the user checks out they are transferred over to the `orders` table and deleted from the `cart` table.

If the selected item is a product then the `promotion_id` value is set to `0` by default. And vice versa if the item selected is a promotion. This is my basic structure:

`cart_products`

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| cart_products_id |    cart_id    |   product_id | promotion_id      | quantity |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 6                |       1       |   5          | 0                 | 2  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

`order_products`

---

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| order_id |   user_id    | product_id | promotion_id      | price    | quantity |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The problem I'm having is trying to `LEFT JOIN` the products/promotions to get the `price` of the selected item. This is my query so far.

```
INSERT INTO order_details (order_id, user_id, product_id, promotion_id, price, quantity)
VALUES(
  '6', 
  '7',
  (SELECT 
    cart_products.product_id, 
    cart_products.promotion_id,
    IF(cart_products.promotion_id = '0', products.price, promotions.price),
    cart_products.quantity

  FROM cart_products


  LEFT JOIN products
  ON cart_products.product_id = products.product_id

  LEFT JOIN promotions
  cart_products.promotion_id = promotions.promotion_id

  WHERE cart_products.cart_id = '6')
)
```

However, this gives my an error `Not unique table/alias`. Does anyone know how I can go about this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of defining values like you have, you can simply select constants so that you can use the INSERT INTO SELECT syntax:

```
INSERT INTO order_details (order_id, user_id, product_id, promotion_id, price, quantity)
SELECT (
    '6', 
    '7',
    cart_products.product_id, 
    cart_products.promotion_id,
    IF(cart_products.promotion_id = '0', products.price, promotions.price),
    cart_products.quantity
  FROM cart_products
  LEFT JOIN products
    ON cart_products.product_id = products.product_id
  LEFT JOIN promotions
    ON cart_products.promotion_id = promotions.promotion_id
  WHERE cart_products.cart_id = '6'
)
```

Also, I believe you forgot an "ON" clause on your second left join

Comment: Thanks, I ended up having to put the `SELECT` inside the parenthesis for it to work otherwise it gave me an error. But I got it to work.